# Is there an eSATA memory stick / thumb drive?

Tags: ssd, product-rec, esata, usb-flash-drive

The new PC I just finished building has eSATA support.  I use a USB stick/thumb drive all the time on my PC for stuff, is there an equivalent available anywhere for eSATA?

*Please list one product per post, and provide a link to the manufacturer's product page.*

Also see [the USB-3 version of this question](https://superuser.com/questions/134163/is-there-a-usb-3-0-thumb-stick-drive).

Comment: @jason: please don't post questions twice.  i see the value in splitting this question into (e)SATA/USB3 versions, so i think both can stay open, but i'm making both questions CW and removing USB3 from this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for example, the [OCZ Throttle eSATA Flash Drive](http://www.ocztechnology.com/jp/products/flash_drives/ocz_throttle_esata_flash_drive) or the [Kanguru e-Flash](https://www.kanguru.com/index.php/flash-drives/basic-flash/kanguru-e-flash).

[image]